# How to get the scene source URL in React-three-fiber

Tags: react-three-fiber, gltf

After modifying the mesh  using the code below, I was wondering how can I get the URL source of the full newly transformed scene as a glb/gltf file, or is even saved internally as such? If it's not saved then do I have to export the modified scene as a separate gltf file instead?

```
    const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/Poimandres.gltf");
    
      return (
        <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null} scale={0.4}>
          <mesh
            onClick={() => downloadGlb()}
            name="myName1"
            castShadow
            receiveShadow
            geometry={nodes.Curve007_1.geometry}
            material={materials["Material.001"]}
            scale={1}
          />
          <mesh
            name="myName2"
            castShadow
            receiveShadow
            geometry={nodes.Curve007_2.geometry}
            material={materials["Material.002"]}
            scale={4}
            rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
          />
        </group>
      );
    }
```